# How to solve non-numeric value encountered Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

code:

```
<tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>
        <span class="lang-chang-label">$</span>
        <span id="total" value="">{{ $price->night + $price->additional_guest + $price->security + $price->cleaning + $price->pet_fee + $price->pool_fee + $price->admin_fee + $price->tax}}</span>
    </td>
    <input type="hidden" id="total_amo" value="{{ $price->night + $price->additional_guest + $price->security + $price->cleaning + $price->pet_fee + $price->pool_fee + $price->admin_fee + $price->tax}}">
</tr>
```

In this code I am simply doing the sum of all value but in my `Price` api I have `tax=""` this is why I had got this error. So, How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: You can't add empty string and numeric value

Comment: How can I do this @SagarGautam? Please tell me. I am new in laravel.

Comment: @omkara You should use "if" conditions for this issue. First, check tax is null or not.

Comment: @omkara I have added answer have a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have encountered is because of string and numeric value addition. So you can get the integer value for empty tax and add like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>
        <span class="lang-chang-label">$</span>
        <span id="total" value="">{{ $price->night + $price->additional_guest + $price->security + $price->cleaning + $price->pet_fee + $price->pool_fee + $price->admin_fee + (int)$price->tax}}</span>
    </td>
    <input type="hidden" id="total_amo" value="{{ $price->night + $price->additional_guest + $price->security + $price->cleaning + $price->pet_fee + $price->pool_fee + $price->admin_fee + (int)$price->tax}}">
</tr>
```

I hope you understand. Feel free to ask if any problem.